# How I can translate sentences from english to another language in Python?

Tags: python

I have to make a translator that translates from English to another language (in my case Hungarian). 
I have the given dict and example (dict is szotar and example is pelda, these are given, and I can't change it). 
I already done something, but I can't figure out, how to ignore the dots and the uppercase letters, and translate them in the same format.

I have to code everything, **can't use any import** things.
Can anyone help me please? Thank you.

```
 szotar={'a':'the',
        'majom': 'monkey',
        'kutya':'dog',
        'szereti':'likes',
        'banánt':'banana',
        'kolbászt':'sausage'}
d = {v: k for k, v in szotar.items()}

pelda='The monkey likes banana. Every dog likes sausage.'
peld=pelda.lower()
pl=peld.split()


def trans(): # függvény
    out="" # kiírt üzenet
    for word in pl:
        if word in d:
            out += d[word] + " " # ha a szótárban található megfelelő szó, azt írja ki, majd egy szóközt tesz utána
        else:
            out += word + " " # ha a szótárban nincs megfelelő szó, marad az eredeti, és szóköz

    print(out) # kiírja a végeredményt
trans()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an approuch ignoring the case of the letters (output all lowercase):

```
szotar={'a':'the',
        'majom': 'monkey',
        'kutya':'dog',
        'szereti':'likes',
        'banánt':'banana',
        'kolbászt':'sausage'}
d = {v: k for k, v in szotar.items()}

def trans(sentense):
    out = ""
    for word in sentense.lower().split():
        for key in d.keys():
            if key in word:
                word = word.replace(key, d[key])
        out += word + ' '
    return out.strip()

pelda='The monkey likes banana. Every dog likes sausage.'
print(trans(pelda))
```

outputs:

> a majom szereti banánt. every kutya szereti kolbászt.

Comment: @ErikGebhard feel free to mark the question as finished when you're done.